# table "Tablename" has no column named "columnname" when it has one

Tags: android, mysql

i create a table with this, while "KEY_IMAGE_PATH" is "image"

```
private class foodieItemDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +KEY_IMAGE_PATH +"         text no null, "
            + KEY_RATING + " text, " + KEY_TITLE + " text);";

    public foodieItemDBOpenHelper(Context c, String dbname,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(c, dbname, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
```

while trying to add data to the database it throws this error:

```
 E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table foodieItems has no column named image
06-12 13:40:34.469  12377-12377/mi.ur.de.foodieappstarterproject E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting rating=3 title=null image=/storage/sdcard/Pictures/FoodieApp/IMG_20150612_134034.jpg
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table foodieItems has no column named image (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO foodieItems(rating,title,image) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Is there anything wrong with my Database setup?

Edit: insert query

```
public long addFoodieItem(FoodieItem item) {
    ContentValues newFoodieValues = new ContentValues();


    newFoodieValues.put(KEY_IMAGE_PATH, item.getImagePath());
    newFoodieValues.put(KEY_RATING, 3);
    newFoodieValues.put(KEY_TITLE, item.getTitle());

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,  newFoodieValues);
}
```

Comment: Shall i see your insert query

Comment: What about these KEY_IMAGE_PATH, KEY_RATING, etc. values

Comment: Change the version of your DB (+1), or completely uninstall, and re-install. And then re-run, the onCreate method on the DB is only called once, and if you update the schema, the new columns will not get created.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask TL;DR - we need a full example not snippets of information

Comment: Your code is working for me. I think you need to try @Elenasys answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, post the definiton of the variables please.

Comment: must be must be TEXT NOT null, see my answer... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommed to you change the query to:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID
        + " INTEGER primary key autoincrement, " +KEY_IMAGE_PATH +" TEXT NOT null, "
        + KEY_RATING + " TEXT, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT);";
```

must be TEXT **NOT** null , this is the reason for what the field defined in `KEY_IMAGE_PATH` can´t be created!

After this change probably you need to uninstall your application because the structure of the table has changed!

Answer (score 0):

In your create table statement, "text no null" is not valid DDL. It should be "text not null" if you want the field to not have null values.

Comment: Are you sure about this. His query is working i tried?

Comment: yes but this doesnt fix the main problem, i also tried it with only "text"

Comment: i copied most of the class from a databasesetup with only 2 columns + id. is there any parameter telling the data base how many columns it should have or are they just added as  i type them in my create statement